# How do I accomplish if-else in Perl Expect?

Tags: perl, expect

I am using [`Expect`](http://p3rl.org/Expect) in Perl to accomplish one task. After sending the command I am expecting either `Success` or `ERROR` as the output, depending on which I need to print to a file saying that it was successful or failed.

```
$exp->expect(30,
    '-re', "Success", printf LOG "Successfully Deleted \n" => sub {exp_last;},
    '-re', "ERROR",   printf LOG "Error in Deletion \n",
);
```

`LOG` is a file handle. If I use this, then even if I get `Success` as the output of the `send` command both the regular expressions are getting executed. In my log file, I am getting

```
Error in Deletion
Successfully Deleted
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

printf is a list operator; the first printf will gobble up all the expect remaining arguments as if you'd said:

```
$exp->expect(30, '-re', "Success",
     printf( LOG "Successfully Deleted \n" =>
         sub {exp_last;},
         '-re',
         "ERROR",
         printf( LOG "Error in Deletion \n" )
     )
 );
```

So the Success case is first printing Error in Deletion, then Successfully Deleted.
You should probably have instead:

```
$exp->expect(30,
    '-re', "Success", printf( LOG "Successfully Deleted \n" => sub {exp_last;} ),
    '-re', "ERROR",   printf( LOG "Error in Deletion \n" ),
);
```

except that there's no reason to use printf instead of print there.

UPDATE: As far as I can understand the Expect docs, that's not how you do multiple patterns at all, and you should be doing:

```
my $which_pattern = $exp->expect(30, "Success", "ERROR");
if ($which_pattern) {
    if ($which_pattern == 1) {
        print LOG "Successfully Deleted \n";
    }
    else {
        print LOG "Error in Deletion \n";
    }
}
```

No need for -re unless you are actually using patterns instead of explicit strings; no idea what you were trying to achieve with the `sub {exp_last;}` bit.

Comment: Hi
  I just modified what u told. But now the reverse happens. First it is printing Successfully Deleted and then it prints Error in Deletion in the log file. I want only one of them to be in my log. If it matches success then Successfully Deleted should be there. If it matches ERROR then Error in Deletion should be there. :(:(

Comment: @shayam: you're going to have to show your new code, possibly including whatever is around the expect call